# Search for next empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data in certain cells to another sheet in a table.

My code copies the data and searches for the cell to be pasted to. If there is a value in the destination cell, it is looped to check the subsequent rows in the same column until it finds an empty cell.
If there's 2000 rows of data currently in the table, it will search all 2000 cells before landing in the 2001st row.

The amount of time taken to execute the code is affected by the size of the table.

Is there any way to execute faster?

Below is a sample, its copying data from two cells.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("K10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Table").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Do While Not (ActiveCell.Value = "")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("G15").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Table").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Do While Not (ActiveCell.Value = "")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
End sub
```

Comment: [Avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/)

Comment: Hello, please help me to understand why I need to avoid these.

Comment: The "Why" is well explained in the link @BruceWayne provided

Comment: ah I see, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following sub.

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim sht1, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Table")

    sht1.Range("K10").Copy sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    sht1.Range("G15").Copy sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @Harun24HR, thank you for your help. Is there anyway to just paste the value alone into the destination cell without affecting the cell's format? Also, if i selected a range such as "K10:K15", how can i transpose it without affecting the cell's format?

Comment: Then you have to use match destination format. Better you can ask a separate question like how to paste cells keeping destination format?

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate it into the code you provided? I tried my original "Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=False" but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear on whether you expect to find interim blank cells within the worksheet's used range or whether you expect to always put the new values at the bottom of the used range. This should work for both scenarios.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")

    With Worksheets("table")
        'force a definition for a .UsedRange on the worksheet
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A") = Chr(32)
        .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1) = ws1.Cells(10, "K").Value
        .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1) = ws1.Cells(15, "G").Value
        'clear the artificial .UsedRange
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").Clear
        'Debug.Print .UsedRange.Address(0, 0)
    End With

End Sub
```